# NextJS dynamimc routing question about slugs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a doubt with nextjs..

I'm building my site like this

```
pages
   [slug]
      index.jsx
   index.jsx
```

so in my slug/index I'm doing this

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const resProducts = await fetch(`${process.env.PRIVATE_ENDPOINT}/products`);
  const products = await resProducts.json();
  const paths = products.data.map((p) => ({
    params: {
      slugProduct: p.slug,
    },
  }));
  return {
    // this should be dynamic
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  };
}
```

My question is what happend if I add a new product in my back office?

Do I have to rebuild with `next build`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is what happend if I add a new product in my back office?
> Do I have to rebuild with next build?

The short answer is NO. If the requested page have not been genereted at build time, Next.js will serve a "fallback" version of the page and will statically generate the requested path HTML and JSON on the background. When the statically generation completed, the browser receives the JSON for the generated path. Subsequent requests to the same path will serve the generated page, just like other pages pre-rendered at build time.

Don't forget to use `router.isFallback` to detect that request is on fallback.

You can see the good document here.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation